# Why does my Jquery draggable jump when placed on one of three droppables?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable, resizable

I've got three resizable droppable areas and one draggable that becomes resizable once dragged onto a droppable.  But the draggable is not staying where I drop it.  It's appending to the correct droppable, but jumping in location, sometimes off the edge of the screen.

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
```

$(".droppable").droppable({

```
            drop: function (e, ui) {
                if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                    x = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();
                x.draggable({
                    helper: 'original',
                    tolerance: 'fit'
                });
                x.resizable({
                    aspectRatio:true,
                    minHeight: 50,
                    minWidth: 50
                });
               var id = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
               x.appendTo(id);
            }

            }
        });
```

$(".droppable").resizable();

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gTwLe/3/

Answer (score 1):

Because you are cloning it and then destroying the original.  So after the clone you need to set the coordinates of the cloned object (x) to match the original.

```
$('.draggable').draggable();


$(".droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {
                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();

                    x.draggable({
                        helper: 'original',
                        tolerance: 'fit'
                    });
                    x.resizable({
                        aspectRatio:true,
                        minHeight: 50,
                        minWidth: 50
                    });
                   var id = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
                   x.appendTo(id);
                    x.offset(ui.helper.offset());
                    ui.helper.remove();
                }

                }
            });

$(".droppable").resizable();
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X4MmR/

Comment: That looks good (correct answer for this question).  Doesn't seem to be solving the problem on my actual application, when I add it.  Don't know if you want to take a look.  If you go to the characters tab and try to take one to a panel, same thing's still happening:  http://thelionscall.com/wp-content/comic-creator/index-testb.html

Comment: You left the ui.helper.remove() on line 123 as well as adding it at line 137.  I think if you eliminate the first remove on line 123 it will work for you.